# Why should I  extend a class?

Tags: java, oop, class, object

Right now I am confused with inheritance and object of class. We can do the same using object as inheritance does.
ok here is first code

```
public class MainForm {
    GUI g = new GUI();
    g.show();
    g.destroy();
}
class GUI {
    void show(){
        ......
    }    
    void destroy (){
        ......
    }
}
```

now second one

```
public class MainForm extends GUI {
    //GUI g = new GUI();
    void show();
    void destroy();
}
class GUI {
    void show(){
        ......
    }    
    void destroy (){
        ......
    }
}
```

both code do the same.Right? then
Why should I extend a class when i can do the same using an object of class?

Comment: Could you give us an example of what you mean? IMHO I don't think the question is very clear...

Comment: Right now I'm confused with your question.

Comment: One of the most compelling reasons is to avoid code duplication.

Comment: It's not very well expressed, but I thought the OP was asking about aggregation vs. inheritance, and when to do each.

Answer (score 2):

Inheritance is often used when you want to create multiple classes of a parent class, without duplicating a lot of logic.  I may have a class named `Animal` which has methods `speak()`, `walk()`, and `sleep()`.  I also may want to have specific instances of `Animal` like `Cat` and `Dog`.

Rather than implementing all three of those methods individually, I can write them in `Animal` and then have my other classes extend Animal to make use of those, as well as add any methods specific to those classes (like `claw()` or `fetch()`).

The benefits are reduced code duplication and better 'abstraction' of the objects.  However, there are some drawbacks as well, as this [article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-08-2003/jw-0801-toolbox.html) points out.  It is important to know when inheritance is useful, and when it is not.